# Will "for i in sorted(my_list):" sort the list every time?

Tags: performance, python-3.x, for-loop

Let's say I have a list `my_list` which is a bunch of numbers, in random order.

I want to print all these numbers, but sorted. If I do:

```
for i in sorted(my_list):
    print(i)
```

does that mean the list will be re-sorted at every iteration? Is there any advantage/disadvantage over the more verbose

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_list)
for i in sorted_list:
    print(i)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

No, the list will not be sorted on every iteration because `sorted()` creates a new list, and the loop will iterate over that.

Of course, if you plan on looping over the sorted list multiple times, it makes sense to store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Both code samples are the same, other than the variable being used in the second. It'll sort once and then it'll iterate over the elements.